# Mock multiple level arrays in java for unit testing

Tags: java, arrays, unit-testing, testing, mockito

Hypothetically I have

```
class Box{
   Item[] items;
}

class Item{
   Toy[] toys;
}

class Toy{
   Color[] colors;
}
```

The method is to test if the Box has green color toy;

```
public bool testHasColor(Box){
   //There will be code here that
   //Streams over each type till we get to color
   // Final point is
   if(color==Color.GREEN){
    return true;
   }
}
```

BoxText.class

```
public void testBoxHasColorGreenMethod(){
    // Need mocking here
}
```

What the best way to mock this Box class for the test case?

Thank you

Comment: I don't really get what you're trying to mock here. Is it correct that you're trying to test ```testHasColor``` method? If so, why would you mock the ```Box``` class, cause it seems to me you'd like to just pass some objects of this class to the ```testHasColor``` method and check whether the result is expected or not.

Comment: Well wihtout knowing anything more of your code, in Java i think you shouldn't use arrays, but some subclass of Collection. But anyways could you give us a bit more detail (also please red this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve )

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to mock any Java APIs. You just need to "mock" some data which is usually not called "mocking" - just testing. So you would just create a test instance of Box and test if your method produces the expected outcome.

```
    Box box = new Box();
    Item item = new Item();
    Toy toy = new Toy();

    box.items = new Item[] {item};
    item.toys = new Toy[] {toy};
    toy.colors = new Color[] {Color.RED, Color.GREEN};
```